# I created a signature using my openssl private key. how to i verify it in java?

Tags: java, openssl, digital-signature, verify

Using the following command to generate a signature on test.txt,

```
$ openssl -dgst -sha256 -sign MyPrivateKey.key -out signaturefile test.txt
```

How do i verify the signature via java?

I've tried using the following method, however, was return with the following error.

```
FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("pubkey.pem");

byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];  

keyfis.read(encKey);

keyfis.close();
X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

FileInputStream signaturefileinput = new FileInputStream("signaturefile");
byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[signaturefileinput.available()]; 
signaturefileinput.read(sigToVerify);   
signaturefileinput.close();
System.out.println(sigToVerify);

Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");

signature.initVerify(pubKey);

FileInputStream datafis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(datafis);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while (bufin.available() != 0) {
    len = bufin.read(buffer);
    signature.update(buffer, 0, len);
};

bufin.close();

boolean verifies = signature.verify(sigToVerify);
System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
```

Can anyone explain to me what causes the error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    at verifyingsignature.encodingsignature.main(encodingsignature.java:31)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: I can't cite it as a duplicate, but see: [Java sign doesn't equal openssl dgst](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968490/java-sign-doesnt-equal-openssl-dgst).

Comment: @jww thanks bro :D i followed the suggestion there and it works!